# Deserializar JSon

Tags: c#, json

Tengo un problema al deszerializar un json que me descargo de un servicio.

la estructura del json es la siguiente:

```
    "{\"d\":{\"tipo\":\"valor\",\"Id\":valor,\"Result\":valor,\"d\":\{\\\"Nombre\\\":[{\\\"idnombre1\\\":valor,\\\"idnombre2\\\":\\\"valor\\\", \\\"idnombre3\\\":\\\"valor\\\", \\\"idnombre4\\\":\\\"valor\\\"}]\\\"baja\\\":valor, \\\"baja2\\\":[]}\"}}"
```

Recibo este json desde una tarea, y lo coloco en un string. Queda de la siguiente manera:

```
    string resultadoJson = prueba.Entrar("parametroacceder1","parametroacceder2").Result;
```

Y seguidamente intento deserializarlo:

```
    RootObject objClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(resultadoJson);
```

Y tengo la siguiente estructura

```
    public class Nombre
    {
       public string idnombre1 { get; set; }
       public string idnombre2{ get; set; }
       public string idnombre3{ get; set; }
       public string idnombre4{ get; set; }
    }
    public class Datum
    {        
       public List<Nombre> program { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootObject
    {
       public int Id { get; set; }
       public int result { get; set; }
       public List<Datum> d { get; set; }
       public string baja { get; set; }
}
```

Cuando el programa va a deserializar me salta un error con el JSON

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

Me podeis hechar una mano para saber que estoy haciendo mal?

Gracias.

Comment: no estoy seguro si el problema pueda venir de las 2 `d` ya que en tu modelo tienes `public List<Datum> d { get; set; }` por donde entiendo la primera `d` seria parte de `Datum` y puede ser el problema

Comment: revisa que tu JSON esté bien formateado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ESPAÑOL**: HOLA  =)... yo uso esta pagina, normal mente para crear clase de un  JSON y que el formato este correcto, se presenta un caso de ejemplo de un JSON y la clase como debería de quedar al final

i use this page to create a perfect Class from json

**http://json2csharp.com/**

example in this case, i have a json

```
{
    "glossary": {
        "title": "example glossary",
        "GlossDiv": {
            "title": "S",
            "GlossList": {
                "GlossEntry": {
                    "ID": "SGML",
                    "SortAs": "SGML",
                    "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                    "Acronym": "SGML",
                    "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                    "GlossDef": {
                        "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                        "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                    },
                    "GlossSee": "markup"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and  the result of this  class is :

```
public class GlossDef
{
    public string para { get; set; }
    public List<string> GlossSeeAlso { get; set; }
}

public class GlossEntry
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string SortAs { get; set; }
    public string GlossTerm { get; set; }
    public string Acronym { get; set; }
    public string Abbrev { get; set; }
    public GlossDef GlossDef { get; set; }
    public string GlossSee { get; set; }
}

public class GlossList
{
    public GlossEntry GlossEntry { get; set; }
}

public class GlossDiv
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public GlossList GlossList { get; set; }
}

public class Glossary
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public GlossDiv GlossDiv { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Glossary glossary { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías traducir la respuesta entera al español, por favor?

Answer (score 0):

Revisando tu `json` veo que no está bien formado, dado que no tiene una estructura correcta, por ejemplo en esta sección de código `":\{\\\"Nombre\\\":[{\`

Tomé como base la estructura de clases que tienes definida (para poder replicar el escenario) y se requiere un `json` muy parecido a este (por lo menos en cuanto a la estructura):

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "result": 2,
    "d": [{
            "program": [{
                    "idnombre1": "id nombre 1",
                    "idnombre2": "id nombre 2",
                    "idnombre3": "id nombre 3",
                    "idnombre4": "id nombre 4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "baja": "1"
}
```

Aquí, la solución sería, que ajustes tu estructura de clases conforma el `json` obtenido, o en su caso, el `json` tenga la estructura de tus clases definidas.

Nota: sería de mayor ayuda que editaras tu pregunta y pusieras la estructura correcta del `json`, con esto, podremos saber exactamente qué tipo de estructura tiene y podríamos darte una respuesta más puntual.